# Why is pointer to generic types not allowed?

Tags: c#, pointers, generics

For example, as an overloaded `[]` setter-getter,

```
    public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                T* p = (T*)hArr.ToPointer(); // hArr is a C++ object pointer(IntPtr)
                return *(p + i);
            }

        }
        set
        {
            unsafe
            {
                T* p = (T*)hArr.ToPointer();
                *(p + i) = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

and compiler complains(underlines) about it "cannot take address of ..." to a managed type `T`.

I know `T` will be only float,double,int or byte in runtime but I don't know how to tell this to compiler so it trusts me.

Why can't I use it, all are pointers anyway, I can overflow any type of array if I'm not careful.

How can I achieve this(with a similar way or another) without being much slower than:

```
    public float this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                return *(p + i);
            }

        }
        set {
            unsafe
            {
                float* p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
                *(p + i) = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't just care about performance here, but also code simplicity too. (one code for all T types) Interfaces can't help here I suppose.

Comment: You can't take a pointer with the `&` operator of reference types (excluding the `string` type)... A value type (a `struct`) can contain a reference type, so in general you can't do a `&` of a `T` (because even restricting `T` to a value type, it could still be "illegal" to have a pointer to it)

Comment: @xanatos also I can't inherit float or int. Does this mean, I must choose between code duplication + performance versus simplicity + not_performance here?

Comment: @huseyn Probably as you said. Perhaps you can write it in IL code directly and have an assembly composed only of IL code... There is already a library done like this

Comment: @xanatos there are aparapi and cudafy similar but I'm writing a very simple library for very simple things.

Comment: What I was speaking about: a library written in IL language https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# [restricts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx) pointer types to

- `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, or `bool`,
- Any `enum` type,
- Any pointer type,
- Any user-defined `struct` type that contains fields of unmanaged types only.

That last point is key, because the compiler must be able to verify that the `struct` to which you are trying to make a pointer is "legal". Otherwise, you would be able to pass `T` that is a `struct` with fields referencing managed types (say, a `string`) which is prohibited.

Since you are interested in providing this behavior for four data types, you should be able to address this problem by providing four overloads:

```
public int GetInt(int i) {
    unsafe {
        var p = (int*)hArr.ToPointer();
        return *(p + i);
    }
public void SetInt(int i, int val) {
    unsafe {
        var p = (int*)hArr.ToPointer();
        *(p + i) = val;
    }
}
public float GetFloat(int i) {
    unsafe {
        var p = (int*)hArr.ToPointer();
        return *(p + i);
    }
public void SetFloat(int i, float val) {
    unsafe {
        var p = (float*)hArr.ToPointer();
        *(p + i) = val;
    }
}
... // and so on
```

The run-time efficiency will remain the same, assuming that the compiler has enough information to resolve overloads at compile time.

Comment: Then if I overload in C++ part instead and then C# part would need only a parameter telling object type and be clear enough using just a struct with array and a parameter field?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Yes, a type designator field should work fine. Unfortunately, there's no clean way to make it work with pointers, because of rather strict rules.